# Bootstrap-Vue how to create a custom column?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

here my code :

```
      <b-table
          hover
          :items="usergroupTable.datas"
          :fields="usergroupTable.fields"
          :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
          :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
          responsive="sm"
      >
        <template #cell(edit)="data">
          <b-button @click="editItem(data.id)">Delete</b-button>
          <b-button @click="editItem(data.id)">Edit</b-button>
        </template>
      </b-table>
```

Here my datas :

```
data() {
    return {
      usergroupTable: {
        filter: null,
        fields: [
          'edit',
          { key: 'usergroupname', label:'User Group Name' , sortable: true},
          { key: 'product', label:'Product' , sortable: true},
          { key: 'seatslimits', label:'Seats Limit' , sortable: true},
          { key: 'expirationdate', label:'Expiration Date' , sortable: true},
          { key: 'lastpayment', label:'Last Payment' , sortable: true},
          { key: 'nextpayment', label:'Next Payment' , sortable: true},
        ],
        datas: [
          { id: 5 ,usergroupname: 'IUT Bordeaux', product: 'Light', seatslimits: '20', expirationdate: '2021/08/01', lastpayment: '', nextpayment: '' },
          { id: 8, usergroupname: 'Admins', product: 'God', seatslimits: '', expirationdate: '', lastpayment: '', nextpayment: '' }
        ],
      }
    }
  },
```

I try to have add and editing button each row, but now Edit column is empty, i don't see my buttons.

Anyone have an idea of the problem ? Thanks !

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors?
Also, that syntax isn't familiar to me but could you try `<template v-slot:cell(edit)="data">`

Comment: Same problem with any error in console with your code <template v-slot:cell(edit)="data">

Comment: I don't getting any JS errors

Comment: When I tried this in the Boostrap-Vue playground, it worked fine and the buttons were displayed. Not sure what's happening in your local environment.

Comment: What version of `Vue` and `BootstrapVue` are you using?

Comment: Vue 2.6 and BootstrapVue 2.0 @Hiws

Comment: BootstrapVue `2.0.0` or `2.0.0-rc.xx`?

Comment: ^2.0.0-rc.28 @Hiws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're using version `2.0.0-rc.28` which has a different naming syntax for `<b-table>` slots.

The syntax you're using is only available in the `2.0.0` release and above, so if you want to use that you need to update.

If you can't upgrade and need to stay on your current version. The syntax is `v-slot:['[field_key]']` for cells, `v-slot:['HEAD[field_key]']` for head cells, and `v-slot:['FOOT[field_key]']` for footer cells.

The reason you have to wrap it in brackets, is because that's the syntax for dynamic when using `v-slot`, and therefore the naming `[field_key]` isn't directly useable. Which is also why this naming syntax only exists in `2.0.0-rc.28`. It's different in prior versions, and later versions.